# Xamarin: Application could not be started

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I can't deploy the hello world application to my Android device (Oneplus 3) from Visual Studio 2015/Xamarin.

I checked for the decorator in MainActivity and MainLauncher is set to `true`.
I checked for the Deploy option in Build->Configuration Manager and it is ticked.
I tried to uninstall the application from the Application Manager on my phone however it wasn't listed.

I tried to uninstall the application with adb howevever it returned this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown package: com.test.helloandroid
    at com.android.server.pm.Settings.isOrphaned(Settings.java:4134)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.isOrphaned(PackageManagerService.java:18757)
    at...
```

So it appears that the package is not even deployed on the phone

The package name starts with a lowercase, no problem with that.

I looked at the Build log and I saw one of the following messages:

```
1>:Deployment failed
1>Mono.AndroidTools.AdbException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
1>   in System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginReceive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
1>   in System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
1>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
1>   in System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
1>   in Mono.AndroidTools.Util.ReadFullAsyncResult.BeginRead(Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncCallback callback)
1>   in Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbSyncClient.BeginReadFailMessage(ReadFullAsyncResult res)
1>   in Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbSyncClient.FileWrite_OnReadStatus(IAsyncResult ar)
1>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
1>   in Mono.AndroidTools.Util.AggregateAsyncResult.CheckError(CancellationToken token)
1>   in Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbSyncClient.EndPush(IAsyncResult result)
1>   in System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
1>Deployment failed because of an internal error: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
1>InternalError
1>Build completed.
1>Deploy successfully on OnePlus A3003
========== Deployment: 1 completed, 0 not completed, 0 ignored ==========
Object reference not set to an object instance.
Object reference not set to an object instance.
Object reference not set to an object instance.
```

or

```
1>:Deployment failed
1>Mono.AndroidTools.AdbException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
1>   in System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginSend(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
1>   in System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
1>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
1>   in System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
1>   in Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbSyncClient.FileWrite_WriteChunk(WriteFileAsyncResult r)
1>   in Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbSyncClient.FileWrite_OnWroteChunk(IAsyncResult result)
1>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
1>   in Mono.AndroidTools.Util.AggregateAsyncResult.CheckError(CancellationToken token)
1>   in Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbSyncClient.EndPush(IAsyncResult result)
1>   in System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
1>Deployment failed because of an internal error: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
1>InternalError
1>Build completed.
1>Deploy successfully on OnePlus A3003
========== Deployment: 1 completed, 0 not completed, 0 ignored ==========
Object reference not set to an object instance.
Object reference not set to an object instance.
Object reference not set to an object instance.
```

(Sorry if there's some non-sense in the exceptions, I translated it)

It seems like Visual Studio or ADB is **having some trouble deploying the application on the phone**, what can the reason be? I tried changing USB ports but I had no luck with that either.

I tried creating a new Blank Xamarin.Android solution and a Native Portable solution and deploying them but it didn't work for me.

I'm not sure what to do at this point. Should I factory reset?

Comment: Have you turned developer mode on on the phone?

Comment: Yes, fast deploy, developer mode and usb debug are turned on